# Android: trying to call method outside of SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am trying to call updateDatabase() method in my content provider from inside my SQLiteOpenHelper class so I will only upgrade the database when version changes and not every time the app compiles. That means I have to put updateDatabase() inside onCreate() or onUpgrade(), but it won't recognize the updateDatabase() method. I am not fluent enough in Android to know what to do, can someone help me?

If I remove static keyword from SQLiteOpenHelper and put updateDatabase() inside onCreate() of SQLiteOpenHelper, then my app opens and closes immediately. Then I get this error: Failed to allocate a 24384046 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 15MB until OOM.

Basically I have an update method outside of SQLiteOpenHelper and I need onUpgrade() to access outside method updateDataBase().

Below is a simplified code of what I actually have and is all I need to illustrate the problem( might have extra curly braces):

```
public class PeriodicTable extends ContentProvider {

        private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

            DatabaseHelper(Context context){
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
                db.execSQL(CREATE_DB_TABLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                              int newVersion) {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ELEMENTS_TABLE_NAME);

                //I want to call updateDatabase() here
                //so I can update database not every time I compile
                onCreate(db);
            }
        }

    public void updateDatabase(){
        Context context = getContext();
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        if(db != null){
            try {
                XmlPullParserHandler parser = new XmlPullParserHandler();
                InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("elements.xml");
                elements = parser.parse(is);

             } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

            try{
                ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations = new ArrayList<>();

                db.beginTransaction();
                for(int i=0; i<elements.size(); i++){
                    ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
                    Element current = elements.get(i);

                    v.put(ATOMIC_NUMBER, current.getAtomicNumber());
                    v.put(SYMBOL, current.getSymbol());
                    v.put(NAME, current.getName());
                    v.put(MOLAR_MASS, current.getMolarMass());
                    operations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(CONTENT_URI).withValues(v).build());

                }
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                applyBatch(operations);

            }catch (final OperationApplicationException e1){
            }
            finally {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
        }


    }
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**
I actually solved the problem by using the below onCreate() method in my content provider, but I would still like to know if you can access updateDatabase from inside the SQLiteOpenHelper class using onUpgrade() or onCreate():

```
public boolean onCreate() {
    Context context = getContext();
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor c = query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, PeriodicTable.ATOMIC_NUMBER);
    if(!c.moveToFirst()){
        updateDatabase();
    }
    return (db == null)? false:true;
}
```

Comment: The upgrade method belongs into the DB helper (that is the purpose of this class to begin with). Why do you think you need it elsewhere?

Comment: @ CL. I didn't know how to access the variables from my content provider inside the DB helper, so I thought maybe I could find a way to call the outside method.